# Can I load/decode an audio file in the Web Audio API without XHRs or <input> with File object.?

Tags: javascript, filereader, game-development, web-audio-api

I want to use the Web Audio API in games without using xhr requests or the File reader.

The reason I want to avoid the xhr requests is that I'm in a game club that has members of varying skill levels and involvement, so asking people to use local hosts or post the game to the internet to avoid CORS issues during development will be problematic.

I want to avoid the file reader because having an extra step for loading the game assetts via an input button seems silly. Although, if there is a simple, robust splash screen solution, that might be OK.

Also, if someone wants to offer up a concise explanation why these CORS policies seem so strict, that would be great. I understand the basic security philosophy, but as a relatively new programmer, I would imagine there ought to be a way for the computer to recognize the file loading is not actually coming from another website or 'origin', but rather from within the same project folder as the rest of the program/game.

Thanks!

Comment: You can load the audio in a regular `<audio>` tag and use that as a source. But what's problematic about using a local server? That's an essential part of web development and incredibly simple to set up.

Comment: Firefox will allow your local page to load assets that are from the same directory / subdirectories as your page. Might be an option for the ones that don't want to set up a webserver, even though it's really easy these days to set one up. For why do browsers have restrictions, it's because they'd loose a lot of customers if any random guy on the internet were able to upload all your hard-drive to their web-server.

Comment: And for a third alternative, you could embed all your assets in your html file as dataURIs, but that will make the whole file a lot heavier, harder to handle for your text editor and harder to maintain all your assets cleanly (+ will require more code to be ran in order to convert back to binary files)

Comment: Thanks guys. @Herohtar, Doesn't extracting/associating to the <audio> tag to the Web Audio API still do some sort of server request and cough up a CORS error?

Comment: @Herohtar, as for the local server situation.... I can see where the club moderator is coming from, as when I was first starting out in the club and had to learn a bunch of new technologies (especially as an overall developer newb), setting up the local host in the beginning would have added more confusion and possible frustration in the beginning. That being said, now that I've been in the club for 6 months and see how limiting avoiding hosting during development can be, it's getting a little frustrating with the workarounds and lack of end goal possibilities.

Comment: @Kaiido, I suppose I can pitch the Firefox solution to the club moderator. Also, I totally get not wanting to allow people to upload the entire hard drive, but to not have a protocol that allows uploading from the same project folder??? At a certain point the user has clearly chosen to run the program and the program will automatically load other kinds of files like scripts and images.

Comment: I can't tell for sure, but I know for a fact that for years FF was even more strict than current Chrome on the file:// protocol, you couldn't even display any resources, while Chrome at least allows it, they just block data-reading from scripts in the name of Same-Origin-Policies. If I had to take a guess as to why they do so, Id' say because they lack confidence in their protection against right escalation, but once again I can't tell for sure.

Comment: @StevenSolof I'm fairly certain the audio tag doesn't do requests in that way, but I've never used it in a situation where CORS was an issue, so maybe that's wrong. I know it will let you get around the issues with XHR/fetch requests that are related to running a page locally from a drive (the `file://` protocol).

Comment: Herohtar, my guess is that creating <audio id="audioTag" src="whatever.mp3> and then using  var audioCtx = new AudioContext();
var source = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(audioTag);   is sending an XHR/fetch under the hood.

Comment: Looks like using Firefox is the appropriate solution. I'll just write in a browser check to the script. If the club members are developing in Firefox, I'll have the script implement the web audio api and it's extra features. If not, I'll use basic audiio with html tags. Thanks!